# Reading child props in parent component with Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I got a component, called Parent and it injects Child, another component.

**Child** has props defined as following:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    foo : 'some-value'
  }
}
```

I would like to access `foo` in **Parent** component like that:

```
class Parent extends Component {
render(){
   //something like this
   <div className={this.props.children.foo}>
      {this.props.children}
   </div>
}
```

**@edit**

After using this `React.Children.toArray` I managed to get the children as an array and `forEach`-it.

But the props are not available in `child.props`.

There is something missing. Anyone have an idea?

Comment: yes, but no property returned in mapStateToProps are there

Comment: Hi, using React Developer Tools I noticed that using redux 'this.props.children' will always be a Connect component (see react-redux library), I think the real problem is to get Connect's children which are the components you defined.

Comment: There is a "withRef" option on connect method that let's you access the wrapped component by default it's set to false https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md

Comment: This video explains access child for both simple and wrapped component with "withRef" option for wrapped components - https://youtu.be/VpdKjocgCtA

Answer (score 0):

As this.props.children can be multiple components you should loop on it

```
render() { 
  this.props.children.forEach((component) => {
    console.log(component.props.foo);
  })

  return ...;
}
```

Take a look at [this](https://jsfiddle.net/kf3nw24e/)

Comment: sounds promising, but it doens't allow me to iterate through children. it says forEach is not a function. And trying `for of` also threw an error

Comment: you can check the type of the children property before (array, object, etc.), that way you will have a clue on how to retrieve the property you want.

Comment: did you try iterating this.props.children on componentDidMount method?

Answer (score 0):

You children can be a single node or multiple node. If single node, you can access the `props` directly else use `map` to iterate over the children and return the `porps`.

Hope this helps!

```
render() {
  const childProps = ! this.props.children instanceof Array
  ? this.props.children.props.foo //returns foo if child is a single node
  : this.props.children.map(child => child.props.foo) // returns array of foo if children is a multiple nodes.

  console.log(childProps)

  return ...;
}
```